# Multi-Value Primary Keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to enforce a property in a model such that for each 'User' field in this particular table, it's corresponding 'Post' field is distinct - and vice versa (i.e., for each particular 'Post' field, the corresponding 'User' field is distinct).  I'm not sure how to do this in Django. I think one approach would be to define the ('User', 'Post') tuple to be a primary key, but it doesn't seem that Django supports this. Is there any other way to enforce this constraint at the field specifications of a Django model (i.e., without doing all the checks in a save() function)? Thanks, appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in the `Meta` class.

Comment: This looks like what I need, thanks! So this would go into the Meta class?

Comment: Yup. `unique-together = (('User', 'Post'),)` in the `Meta` class. Edit: `unique-together = ('User', 'Post')` should work also

Comment: Appreciate it. I'd upvote but i don't have enough street-cred, apparently.